# How to estimate the similarity between different cubic curves using R

Tags: r, statistics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgu14.png)All three variables were able to fit a cubic functional relationship with the buffer distance, and in order to estimate the relationship between the changes of these three variables because these curves are relatively similar from the graphs.
Is there a quantitative way to estimate the similarity between the cubic function curves? Even if it is an opposite mirror relationship?

Comment: Define "similarity". Maybe this is useful? https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/231059/11849

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I have no idea why the model 2 need to muliple g? and if it is ok for my question. Can you check my picture in the question.